# Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command to convert an avi,mov,m4v video files to flv format via FFMPEG

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '/home/public_html/files/video_1355440448.m4v' -s '640x360' -sameq -ab '64k' -ar '44100' -f 'flv' -y /home/public_html/files/video_1355440448.flv

[flv @ 0x68b1a80] requested bitrate is too low
Output #0, flv, to '/home/files/1355472099-50cadce349290.flv':
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 640x360, q=2-31, pass 2, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: adpcm_swf, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
-------------------------------
RESULT
-------------------------------
Execute error. Output for file "/home/public_html/files/video_1355472099.avi" was found, but the file contained no data. Please check the available codecs compiled with FFmpeg can support this type of conversion. You can check the encode decode availability by inspecting the output array from PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo().
```

But if I manually used this command then its working

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '/home/public_html/files/video_1355440448.m4v' -s '640x360' -sameq -ab '64k' -ar '44100' -f 'flv' -y /home/public_html/files/video_1355440448.flv
```

Comment: As you surely have followed what was suggested in the error message: *" Please check the available codecs compiled with FFmpeg can support this type of conversion. You can check the encode decode availability by inspecting the output array from PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo()."* - Share the outcome with your question.

Comment: Also, can you please identify which part exactly is wrong of: *"Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"*? Can you please turn the *maybe* into a definite fact?

Comment: Same error here. I had 2 process using same ffmpeg command. Problem was a cron job overlapping.

Answer (score 17):

1. This is because you have two streams and output will be encoding then resizing, see your output messages:

   ```
   Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
   Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
   ```

   ... you use `adpcm_swf` audio and `yuv420p` video

   The answer is very simple, you need to put `copy` as your audio codec ...

   **See my example with video mpeg4,yuv420p and audio ac3 ...**

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf scale=720:-1 -acodec copy -threads 12 output.mkv
   ```

   this will change first size = 720 with aspect ratio = -1 (unknown). Also you need to use:

   ```
   -acodec copy -threads 12
   ```

   If don't use this you will have one error.
   For example: When I used it, the output encoding messages show me this and it works well:

   ```
   [h624 @ 0x874e4a0] missing picture in access unit93 bitrate=1034.4kbits/s    
   Last message repeated 1163 times5974kB time=53.47 bitrate= 915.3kbits/s
   ```
2. You need to use for flv format file, something like this:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 output.flv
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You are given an error message

```
[flv @ 0x68b1a80] requested bitrate is too low
```

You need to change bitrate to a valid. It is better if you use a different codec

```
-acodec libmp3lame
```

And remove the option `-sameq`. This option does NOT mean 'same quality'. Actually means 'same quantizers'!

Comment: just try to remove the option `-sameq`

Comment: I have using ffmpeg version SVN-r26402 is stable or not

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem due to size constraints. The original image size was strange (width=1343), meaning that when I tried to specify a new size with -s, *any* rounding error caused problems. Make sure that the new image size can have the exact same aspect ratio!

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same issue

```
- requested bitrate is too low
```

and just resolved this issue by lowering down the bit rate

```
by adding -b:a 32k
```